# fitting Poisson GLM model for a very large spatial data set

Tags: r, spatial, glm, poisson

I have a data set including "longitude", "latitude" and "month" of points (events). I converted points into SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with size 1km*1km. Then I counted the number of points in each grid as a dependent variable ("Freq").

Now, I want to fit GLM. but I don't know whether is correct if I consider "longitude" and "latitude" as predictors.

My code for this looks like below:

```
fit = glm(Freq ~  longitude + latitude + month , family=poisson(link=log), data=events)
```

Comment: in all likelihood, the relationship among lat, lon & your `Freq` is _highly_ nonlinear, non-monotone. do you think your specified model is likely to capture this functional relationship?

Comment: how large is "very large"?  (How many lat/long values, how many months, how many observations in total?) What is the goal of your analysis?

Comment: @BenBolker, I use the point process nature dataset which is lightning strikes occurrence. the data is collected over ten years and observations in total are almost 100000. The aim is estimating the probability of lightning strikes for particular location and time.

Comment: shameless self-promotion of our paper for forecasting sparse event counts on a grid: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02858

Comment: Are there 100000 lightning strikes or 100000 gridded values? (Or are both about the same order of magnitude? If so, your grid might be too fine-grained, unless the strikes are *very* aggregated ...)

Comment: I don't know any of the implementation details of @MichaelChirico's approach.  If you want an alternative, I would suggest fitting an additive model with a Poisson response, e.g. see [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Space_time_smoothing_in_R.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @BenBolker , this link is really helpful.